# Eclipse maven project compliance

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying for more than two hours now to fix my maven setup in Eclipse but I am getting from one error to the next and no solution in the intenet worked for me.

Also maven -> update project did not solve the problem.

Also setting java compiler on build path results in no success. Eclipse suggests always to set it back to 1.5 (manually setting 1.7 no success)

I am not sure which entry in my pom.xml causes the error.

I am getting these errors

[image]

my pom.xml

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.se.bac</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mitarbeiterverwaltung</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>1.0.0.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>
        <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jbossHome>X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1</jbossHome>
                    <port>9990</port>
                    <server-config>standalone.xml</server-config>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run wildfly and deploy application for integration tests. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>wildfly-run</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Integration test teardown. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>wildfly-shutdown</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>undeploy</goal>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 7 APIs we want to import. Any 
                dependencies from org.jboss.spec will have their version defined by this 
                BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
            in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JSON API to build JSON Objects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-json-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my settings for the project:

[image]

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:start (wildfly-run) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
[INFO] JBOSS_HOME=X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1

[INFO] Server is starting up.
Okt 17, 2017 8:42:00 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
Okt 17, 2017 8:42:00 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
Okt 17, 2017 8:42:00 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final

20:42:02,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
20:42:02,676 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:42:02,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.6.Final)
20:42:02,680 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
20:42:02,732 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.0.Final
20:42:02,737 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final starting
20:42:02,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
20:42:02,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:42:02,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
20:42:02,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
20:42:02,931 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
20:42:02,942 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
20:42:02,945 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
20:42:02,985 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
20:42:03,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
20:42:03,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
20:42:03,098 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDM0111: Keystore X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
20:42:03,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1\standalone\deployments
20:42:03,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.zip" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.zip")
20:42:03,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war" (runtime-name: "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war")
20:42:03,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar")
20:42:03,498 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
20:42:03,578 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.12) 
20:42:03,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
20:42:03,773 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
20:42:03,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
20:42:03,777 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
20:42:03,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MySqlDS]
20:42:03,924 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
20:42:04,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
20:42:04,480 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
20:42:04,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war#primary'
20:42:04,576 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]


20:42:05,115 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final)
20:42:05,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war#primary'
20:42:05,565 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) IJ000407: No lazy enlistment available for MySqlDS
20:42:05,578 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
20:42:05,615 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Envers integration enabled? : true
20:42:05,834 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:05,839 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK
20:42:05,839 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK
20:42:06,013 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:06,254 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:06,254 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:07,030 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:07,034 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.se.bac.service.ProjectResourceEJB from Application class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:07,034 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.se.bac.service.CustomerResourceEJB from Application class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:07,034 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.se.bac.service.EmpResourceEJB from Application class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:07,099 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Mojarra 2.2.13.SP4  für Kontext '/Mitarbeiterverwaltung' wird initialisiert.
20:42:08,049 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
20:42:08,070 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/Mitarbeiterverwaltung' for server 'default-server'
20:42:08,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar")
20:42:08,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.zip" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.zip")
20:42:08,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war" (runtime-name : "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war")
20:42:08,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
20:42:08,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:42:08,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:42:08,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.CR1 (WildFly Core 3.0.1.Final) started in 7545ms - Started 561 of 789 services (359 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (wildfly-run) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Mitarbeiterverwaltung] in [C:\Users\Florian\git\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\target\Mitarbeiterverwaltung]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Florian\git\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [149 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Florian\git\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\target\Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (wildfly-run) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (wildfly-run) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
20:42:08,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1\standalone\data\content\8a\f5ae904748ce46128a1e81676f9d16e422dac3\content
20:42:08,828 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/Mitarbeiterverwaltung' from server 'default-server'
20:42:08,862 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war#primary'
20:42:08,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war#primary'
20:42:08,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war (runtime-name: Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war) in 86ms
20:42:08,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war" (runtime-name: "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war")
20:42:09,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
20:42:09,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war (runtime-name: Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war) in 598ms
20:42:09,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war" (runtime-name: "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war")
20:42:09,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
20:42:09,928 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war#primary'


20:42:10,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war#primary'
20:42:10,143 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
20:42:10,155 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) Envers integration enabled? : true
20:42:10,176 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:10,176 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK
20:42:10,177 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK
20:42:10,192 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:10,210 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:10,210 INFO  [org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: org.se.bac.data.model.ProjectEmployee_PK (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
20:42:10,394 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:10,394 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.se.bac.service.CustomerResourceEJB from Application class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:10,394 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.se.bac.service.ProjectResourceEJB from Application class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:10,394 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.se.bac.service.EmpResourceEJB from Application class org.se.bac.service.RESTApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
20:42:10,404 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) Mojarra 2.2.13.SP4  für Kontext '/Mitarbeiterverwaltung' wird initialisiert.
20:42:10,994 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
20:42:10,995 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/Mitarbeiterverwaltung' for server 'default-server'
20:42:11,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0013: Redeployed "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war"
20:42:11,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war" with deployment "Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war"
20:42:11,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location X:\5. Semester\Bac1\wildfly-11.0.0.CR1\standalone\data\content\42\5aae1bfd48b2702b404b259e1baf3eb71b84bf\content
[INFO] 

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ Mitarbeiterverwaltung ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Florian\git\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\target\Mitarbeiterverwaltung.war to C:\Users\Florian\.m2\repository\org\se\bac\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Mitarbeiterverwaltung-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Florian\git\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\pom.xml to C:\Users\Florian\.m2\repository\org\se\bac\Mitarbeiterverwaltung\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Mitarbeiterverwaltung-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.908s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 17 20:42:11 CEST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Start a Maven build (`install`) and report the results.

Comment: I have added the output above

Comment: Check the file `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` in `.settings` folder of your project, check the facets `<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>` and `<installed facet="java" version="1.8"/>`. save and do maven->update project in eclipse.

Comment: Hello, I have tried it but no change. I have Java 1.8 installed on my Laptop and in my Eclipse Kepler I can only choose for Java Compiler 1.7 Version. Can this cause the problem? When I have Java 1.8 installed and Compiler only 1.7 in Eclipse?

Comment: Your Maven build is successful. So you don't have Build problems. Do you have runtime problems? Remember that error messages in Eclipse can be right or wrong, the real truth is the build.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I solved the problem by installing the newest version of eclipse where I can choose Java 1.8. Now I do not have any errors more!